# Function that returns the closest rated city's team in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have tables league(city,team) and rankings(city, rating) (all are strings except for rating which is real type). There are extra cities in ranking that are not necessarily in league. I am trying to create a function called closestRating that would take in a city and return the name of the team whose city has the smallest ratings gap (meaning not itself) with the city in the function parameter or the name of the team corresponding to the city parameter if the city we are looking for also exists in league. (City is defined as varchar(20) in both league and rankings).

My attempt at it has some really weird syntax errors

```
    CREATE FUNCTION closestRating (city varchar(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) AS $$
    DECLARE minimum real;
    DECLARE rat real;
    BEGIN
        SET minimum = -1;
        FOR r.city, rating IN (SELECT r.city, r.rating FROM rankings r)
        LOOP
            IF city = r.city
            BEGIN
                SET rat = rating;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        FOR rating IN (SELECT r.city, r.rating FROM rankings r, league l WHERE r.city = l.city)
        LOOP
            IF minimum = -1 OR minimum < ABS(rat – rating)
            BEGIN
                SET minimum_dist = ABS(r – rating);
                SET rat = rating;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN (SELECT team from rankings, league WHERE rating = rat));
    END;
    $func$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: **Always** include the complete error messages. But obvious errors are: there is no `set` in PL/pgSQL (see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) the `IF` requires a `then` (also clearly documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) and the function is defined as `returns varchar` so you can not return a *set* of rows (which is actually a cross join between rankings and league - which almost certainly wrong - you just haven't noticed yet)

Comment: I think this can be done with a single SQL query, no need for the slow-by-slow approach with the loops. **Edit** your question and add the complete table structure, some sample data and the expected output based on the sample data.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to edit.

Comment: this sounds a bit like collaborative filtering...check out the smlar extension. https://www.pgcon.org/2012/schedule/attachments/252_smlar-2012.pdf

Comment: You _can_ edit your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this data:

```
create table league (
    city varchar(20),
    team varchar(20)
);
create table rankings (
    city varchar(20),
    rating real
);
insert into rankings (city, rating) values
    ('citya', 1),('cityb', 1.1),('cityc', 1.01),('cityd', 1.102),('citye', 1.2)
;
insert into league (city, team) values
    ('citya', 'teama'),('cityc', 'teamc'),('citye', 'teame')
;
```

This query will return the expected output:

```
with given_city as (
    select rating, city
    from rankings
    where city = 'citya'
)
select l.team
from
    league l
    inner join
    rankings r using (city)
    cross join
    given_city gc
order by abs(r.rating - gc.rating)
limit 1
;
 team  
-------
 teama
```